# Can hardware affect the time complexity of an algorithm?

Tags: big-o

If you impose the restriction that the hardware must be finite in size, I would think that any architecture improvements like parallelism or caching couldn't change the time complexity. Even if memory access took O(n) like on a turing machine, with finite memory there would be an upper limit on time making it O(1).

Comment: See this article: http://www.ilikebigbits.com/blog/2014/4/21/the-myth-of-ram-part-i

Comment: @meowgoesthedog Those articles were great! Thanks for sharing.